# How to create ship painted metal panels material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, normals

Can someone tell me how i can get similar bumps on a surface as the images below
[image]
[image]

So far i have just unwrapped the hull and used the following material with a musgrave texture.
[image]

The model can be downloaded [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ad6d4c85fc5517dbb2b0ed2dc9b2b0af20210112134023/7556d0c4edd129cb532a46c38e3f98ce20210112134039/76dcc0)

I would like to add some realism on the hull so any advise is highly appreciated!

P.S Rendering with cycles.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you having trouble exactly in the process of creating the material? Are you using cycles or EEVEE? Please read, [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)...

Comment: @Timaroberts thanks for your comment. I updated accordingly!

Comment: thanks for the edit, much clearer now :)

Answer (score 2):

First, the initial results are good.

I would say don't connect the same thing to both normal sockets.  *Do* use the clearcoat normal (and I'm a fan of including whatever level of microdetail you want) but consider mixing in much larger scale imperfection as well, to try and coax this type of imperfect reflection from the clearcoat layer.

[image]

Make another bump node for the surface Normal socket.

Perhaps this type of wave texture:

[image]

And maybe add (clamped) some noise in for good measure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That's very helpful! Thank you!